# Converting overlapping multipart lines into polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, multipart

I have a number of multipart lines that form rectangles, each with a unique identifier. Imagine having building footprints as lines, but many intersecting one another like in the attached image. When I run feature to polygon in ArcGIS Pro, I get 7 polygons.

How do I tweak the analysis so I only get 3?

I'm also versed in Python if there is a programmatic way to go about this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without writing code you could run three tools manually or create a small model in ModelBuilder which:

1. Uses [Split By Attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm) to create a separate feature class for each rectangle (as lines);
2. Converts each rectangle from lines to polygons using [Feature To Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm) which needs an Advanced level license; and
3. Appends the polygons in those multiple polygon feature classes into a single feature class using [Append](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm)

Comment: If you're versed in python you can create the polygons by recycling the vertices of the boundary. Polylines are made from paths and polygons are made from rings, paths and rings are nearly identical so iterating the geometry first part vertices into an array can be constructed into a polygon - without an advanced license. A study of https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001v000000 serves as a starting point for the OP to understand how to generate geometries with arcpy.